# Is there a way to store counter in localStorage and update it on UI when button is click?

Tags: javascript, css, json, local-storage, counter

I create a counter and store  it to local Storage. when I click on save button to store it to local storage and also display it on UI, it get store to local storage  does not store on UI when I refresh the page.
now if click on save to store the counter value to local storage and update the UI it doesn't.

```
div class="main-container">
        <span class="span">0</span>
        <div class="btn-con">
        <button class="plus-btn">increase</button>
        <button class="minus-btn">decrease</button>
        <button class="save-btn">save</button>

        </div>
        
        
    </div>
```

```
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus-btn');
const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.minus-btn');
const saveBtn = document.querySelector('.save-btn')
const span = document.querySelector('.span');


// EVENTLISTENERS
plusBtn.addEventListener('click', plus);
minusBtn.addEventListener('click', minus);
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', getCount );

// apdates UIert


//FUNCTIONS

var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0;

function plus() {
    counter ++ ;
    span.innerText = counter;
    //localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
    //span.innerText = localStorage.getItem('counter');
     
};


function minus() {
    counter -- ;
    span.innerText = counter;
    //localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
    
};

 function getCount() { 
    //localStorage.getItem('counter
     span.innerText = counter;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
  


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make an assignment when loading

```js
  var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0;

  span.innerText = counter
```

Comment: sure! it works now. thanks, can we get in touch on social media?

Comment: @AzongoIsmail Maybe you can invite me in the chat room, we can communicate together